# CSV Reader: TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'NoneType' and 'str'

Tags: python, csv, python-3.x

I have CSV reading script that is suddenly running into problems. My work flow is that I take a csv list rows of information, convert it to utf-8 using notepad. Then I run this code on it.

Now I'm starting to get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\x\x\x\uploader\user_db_and_upload.py", line 121, in <module>
csv_dict_reader(f_obj, x_obj, n_obj)
File "C:\Users\x\x\x\uploader\user_db_and_upload.py", line 57, in csv_dict_reader
name = data_in_list[x]['firstname'] + " " + data_in_list[x]['surname']
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'NoneType' and 'str'
```

When I attempt to try the process over again I run into a separate error saying that it cannot find a different key (i.e.there is a key called 'firm' and it will swap to saying this is now the KeyError and it cannot find it.)

What I guess I'm confused about is that if I have converted it to utf-8 and changed no code whatsoever, why I find myself in this position. Was the original code wrong? Anything will help.

code:

```
def csv_dict_reader(file_obj, x_obj, n_obj):

    data_in_list = []
    x=0

    reader = csv.DictReader(file_obj, delimiter=',')
    f = csv.writer(x_obj, delimiter=',', quotechar='"')
    f1= csv.writer(x_obj, delimiter=',', quotechar='"')
    f2= csv.writer(n_obj, delimiter=',', quotechar='"')

    f1.writerow(["name","email","external_id","details","notes","phone","role","restriction","organization","tags"])
    f2.writerow(["name","email","phone","office","department", "role"])

    for row in reader:
        data_in_list.append(row)

        name = data_in_list[x]['firstname'] + " " + data_in_list[x]['surname']
        firm = data_in_list[x]['firm']
        phone = data_in_list[x]['phone']
        email = data_in_list[x]['email']
        office = data_in_list[x]['office']
        department = data_in_list[x]['dept']
        details = ","
        notes = ","
        role = data_in_list[x]['role']
        restrictions = ","
        tags = ","

        f.writerow([name] + [email] + [details] + [phone] + [role] + 
               [restrictions] + [firm] + [tags] + [office] + [department])
        f2.writerow([name] + [email] + [phone] + [office] + [department] + [role])

        x= x+1
    return data_in_list

if __name__ == "__main__":

    with open("stafflist11.csv") as f_obj:
        with open("new.csv", "w") as x_obj:
            with open("user_databse_nepo.csv", "w") as n_obj:   
                csv_dict_reader(f_obj, x_obj, n_obj)
```

Comment: Any reason to open x_obj  both as f and  f1?

Comment: No. I think I can just use f. to write the initial line and the line within the for loop. But I don't think that fixes the issue. I believe it has something to do with my csv_reader. When I swap the first key (the one that defines the columns) it turns out fine. For example if I have name,firm. It will error out and I will get the KeyError. But if I swap this and make it firm,name there is no compiler error.

Comment: If the column name is `name`, why do you try to do `data_in_list[x]['firstname']`?

Comment: Why do you convert to utf-8?  Are you sure the file opens are specifying that encoding?

Comment: The purpose of the script it to reorganize an existing csv file. data_in_list[x]['firstname'] refers to a column in the unorganized csv file. [name] refers to the new column the script is writing to with the proper organization.

Comment: You don't need to convert it to utf-8 to reorganize it.

Comment: I guess what I don't understand is why I don't get a KeyError when I swap the two columns around. 

ntloginid,firm,surname,firstname,phone,mobile,email,role,office,dept (this works)

firm,ntloginid,surname,firstname,phone,mobile,email,role,office,dept (this does not work)

Comment: @martineau you shouldn't be opening files in binary mode for csv.  The docs show text mode.  But you do need to choose the correct encoding.  Which in this case should be utf-8 as in the docs: `with open('some.csv', newline='', encoding='utf-8') as f:`

Comment: If you can't work out what's going on just add `print(row)` in the loop before the place the error happens.  It should be pretty clear then.

Comment: It was unclear where the "name,firm" came from, since it is not in the code. Anyways, on top of othet things, you can replace each `data_in_list[x]` with `row` since you do not make use of the list. It is clearer.

Comment: Thanks @MathiasEttinger

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that you are encoding the files in utf-8 but opening them in python as if they were in your default encoding. I don't know what your default encoding is - it depends on your system and locale - but it probably isn't utf-8.

The easiest fix for that is just not to use notepad to re-encode.

I think you want to write the reorganised files as utf-8: but that's easy. Just change the statements where you open the files in write mode to specify `encoding=utf-8`.